# Problem in configuration of Tiva TM4C1294NCPDT on Code Composer Studio

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, configuration

I am using **code composer studio** and using the microcontroller below, I used Energia software to run a simple program and it runs, but when I use CCS and try to flash an example program for this MCU provided by ti , it gives me an error message .
I think that problem is from target configuration file .

In the target configuration file :
I set the connection **Stellaris In-Circuit Debug interface**,
and Board or Device : **Tiva TM4C1294NCPDT**.

Then this window pops up:

[image]

[image: U]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized what I've to do. I need root privilege,so I have to update the `.desktop` file of code composer.

```
$ nano 'Code Composer Studio 9.2.0.desktop'
```

I edited the file to be :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Version=0.9.4
Name=Code Composer Studio 9.2.0
Comment=Launches CCStudio
Icon=/home/abdo/ti/ccs920/ccs/doc/ccs.ico
Exec=sudo /home/abdo/ti/ccs920/ccs/eclipse/ccstudio
Terminal=true
Path=/home/abdo/ti/ccs920/ccs/eclipse
```

then, it works properly.